# Spring web application, removing <welcome-file-list> from web.xml gives 404

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am working on a simple Spring Hibernate Maven web application.

If I remove the `<welcome-file-list>..` from the `web.xml`, it still does not go to the controller , but gives 404.

I tried various solutions in answers in SO but not successful yet.

Here is my code:

**web.xml:**(webapp/web.xml)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <display-name>App</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

    </web-app>
```

**springmvc-servlet.xml:**(webapp/springmvc-servlet.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="app" />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app" p:username="root"
      p:password="root" /> 
    <!-- 10.210.13.251 -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

**Controller:**(main/java/app/contollers/UserController)

```
package app.controller;

import app.model.UserMaster;
import app.service.UserMasterService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserMasterService userMasterService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getHomePage(){
        return new ModelAndView("register", "userForm", new UserMaster());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserMaster userMaster){
        userMasterService.saveUser(userMaster);
        return "success.html";
    }
}
```

**register.jsp:**(webapp/views/register.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form:form action="register" method="post" commandName="userForm">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Spring MVC Form Demo - Registration</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="userid" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here, why does it give me 404? 
I use Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE

**Screenshot of my project structure**
[image]

Comment: Why must you remove it?

Comment: Since you're already giving `"/"` as the mapping for your class, you should use mappings `""` and `"register"` for the methods, as the class mapping is prepended to them in all cases.

Comment: @takendarkk, if I dont remove it, it tries to find that file specified as welcome file, which I dont have, so again throws 404.

Comment: Then your servlets must not be registered correctly because having the welcome file list alongside applications is common.

Comment: @Kayaman, yeah thanks, but the solution did not solve my problem

Comment: InternalResourceViewResolver is missing from configuration file.

Comment: @vijayraj34, tried adding that, no luck.

Comment: @takendarkk, can you please see my code and suggest me where I am doing wrong

Comment: Let me ask, if I type in yourwebsite.com which class should I very taken to? DispatcherServlet or UserController? From your code I cannot tell because they both listen at the same url, `/`.

Comment: I want it to go to the UserController

Comment: I think there is a mismatch in component-scan base package value. In your configuration file its mentioned "coolcook" package to scan. But actually your controller is in "app.controller" package which makes sense why the controller is not detected.

Comment: Edited the code @vijayraj34, thanks

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Nope not working yet

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot of project directory structure with folders open?

Comment: @OutOfMind we are waiting for your response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139200/discussion-between-outofmind-and-vijayraj34).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! The issue was with the path of `views` folder in `InternalResourceViewResolver`

**Should be:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**Instead of:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/views/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First check viewsolver in your code.

```
  <bean id = "viewResolver"

    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/views/" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

And there is no need of writing RequestMapping below @Controller.The code should look like:

```
  @Controller
  public class UserController
```